# Get all Azure Data Factory pipeline runs using .NET sdk

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-data-factory

How can be loaded all pipeline runs from Azure Data Factory using .NET SDK in one HTTP query to the factory? 
I have tried the `QueryByFactoryWithHttpMessagesAsync` method but it returns only 100 last runs.

```
var filter = new RunFilterParameters(DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.Now);

return client.PipelineRuns.QueryByFactoryWithHttpMessagesAsync(
                dataFactoryParameters.ResourceGroup,
                dataFactoryParameters.DataFactoryName,
                filter).Result.Body.Value;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a code sample, but the [QueryByFactoryAsync method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.datafactory.pipelinerunsoperationsextensions.querybyfactoryasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Management_DataFactory_PipelineRunsOperationsExtensions_QueryByFactoryAsync_Microsoft_Azure_Management_DataFactory_IPipelineRunsOperations_System_String_System_String_Microsoft_Azure_Management_DataFactory_Models_RunFilterParameters_System_Threading_CancellationToken_) returns a [PipelineRunsQueryResponse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.datafactory.models.pipelinerunsqueryresponse?view=azure-dotnet) instance, which includes a [ContinuationToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.datafactory.models.pipelinerunsqueryresponse.continuationtoken?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Management_DataFactory_Models_PipelineRunsQueryResponse_ContinuationToken) property. You should be able to use that to get the next group of values.